# PhpStorm/Symfony - navigate to twig file

Tags: php, symfony, twig, phpstorm, apache-storm

I need help getting PhpStorm to correctly navigate to my twig files. E.g, in my controller, I have:

```
return $this->render('user/schedule.html.twig');
```

If I hit command and click on the `user/schedule.html.twig`, it SUPPOSED to take me directly to my file (living in the project root under `templates/user/schedule.html.twig`).  However, instead PhpStorm says:

> Cannot find declaration to go to

I believe this needs to be configured in the Symfony Twig plugin, under "Preferences -> Lang & Frameworks -> Symfony -> Twig/Template", but I cannot seem to find the right setup to make this work. Any advice please?

Comment: Do you have symfony plugin for phpstorm?

Comment: Such navigation and other Symfony-specific stuff is provided by Symfony plugin.

Comment: Works as expected in PHPStorm 2020.2.3 and Symfony Support plugin 0.21.204 on Windows 10

Comment: Go to settings, plugins, marketplace and search symfony then enable plugin and restart phpstorm

Answer (score 2):

you need to explicitly enable the symfony Plugin for the project